# What is the time complexity of the following function - O(n^3) or something else?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Is it O(n^3) or O(n^4)? I am not sure whether the time complexity is O(n^3) or O(n^4)

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= i*i;j++)
    {
        if( j % i == 0)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < j;k++){sum++;}
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: I always wonder about the point of questions like this, where figuring out the complexity of the current solution is probably more work than creating an O(N) solution, and only marginally less than an O(1) solution.

Answer (score 4):

The outer loop for `i` runs `n` times.

The middle loop for `j` runs `i * i` times for *each* outer loop, and `i` is linear to `n`. That brings the complexity up to `n[outer] * n2[middle]`.

The inner loop for `k` runs `j` times for *each* middle loop, and `j` is linear to `n2`. However, that `if` statement removes inner loop execution for `i - 1` middle loop iterations per set of `i`, effectively making the inner count linear to `i` rather than to `i2`.

That brings the complexity up to `n[outer] * n2[middle] * n[inner]`.

In other words, `O(n4)`.

Comment: Hey, am trying to understand your reason, but can't get around why we are not considering j%i, it won't be simply be o(n^2)

Comment: Isn't the inner loop linear to i? since it will execute only for i,2i,3i and so on?

Comment: @SarimAhmed: you may be right, I misread the expression as `!=`.  Will adjust.

Comment: cool, I was really thinking how it can be O(n^5)

Answer (score 2):

It should be O(n^4), lets breakdown each loop

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++)
```

It runs from 1 to n therefore time complexity here is O(n). Then

```
for(int j = 1; j <= i*i;j++)
```

From 1 to i ^ 2. So in worst case it runs for O(n ^ 2). Then the inner most loop depends on

```
 if( j % i == 0)
```

It's only true whenever j is a multiple of i, so for each i, j will be i,2i,3i,4i,5i,... i^2, and then the loop runs till j

```
for(int k = 0; k < j;k++)
```

which in worst case will be i^2, for eg

1. i = 1, k runs for 1 time,
2. i = 2, j can be 2 or 4, so k runs 2 for (j = 2) + 4 for (j = 4) = 6
3. i = 3, k = 18

which forms a pattern of i,2i,3i, 4i ... i^2, we get this

```
i^2 * (1 + i) / 2
```

If we sum the value of i from 1 to n. and remember the above polynomial is of degree 3, when we sum the above polynomial from 1 to n we will polynomial of degree 4

Therefore the time complexity is O(n^4)

Comment: Given you an upvote since your answer was more correct than my initial one :-) However, just one note: the pattern you have, `i,2i,3i, 4i ... i^i`, I think that final term should be `i*i` (or `i^2`), should it not?

Comment: Ya @paxdiablo :), for some reason have been typing i^2 as i*i, thanks for pointing it out